# Push my location marker on drawed route

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, gps

I am using `Google Maps v3 API in Android`. I need to show my location while I'm travelling from A to B along a route.

I'm drawing polyline as route from A to B. And I need to write marker of my location on route polyline. Android google maps have big accuracy, then i need push my gathered location into polyline. Have anyone idea how can i push my location marker from current location to nearest point of my route ?

Comment: how could you use v3 api if the max version for android is v2?

Comment: You can try to use the `Roads api` [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/roads/). It allows you to map GPS coordinates to the geometry of the road.

Comment: Roads api is ok, but it will calculate route from history of geopoints, i need push my actual position to the route calculated from directions api ... like some kind of navigation where i am on route, no 5 meter outside in building or forest, field ...